# mysql performance why update 1000 rows take 3-4 times more than update one row * 1000

Tags: mysql, sql

If I try

```
UPDATE my_table t1, my_table t2 
SET 
    t1.hash1 =  UNHEX(MD5(t2.original)),
    t1.hash2 =  UNHEX(MD5(t2.translated))
WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

I got this result

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)
```

But if I try this:

```
UPDATE my_table t1, my_table t2 
SET 
    t1.hash1 =  UNHEX(MD5(t2.original)),
    t1.hash2 =  UNHEX(MD5(t2.translated))
WHERE t1.id < 1000;
```

The result is:

```
Query OK, 998 rows affected (5 min 13.66 sec)
```

Espected 0.09 * 1000 / 60 = 1.5 min

I have used first that from https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/124733/146439:

```
SET GLOBAL join_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 42;
```

Have there other tricks to improve the update time ? (MyISAM engine)

Comment: have you index  on t1.id ??

Comment: Yes. Is unique primary key

Comment: Have not two tables I use self join for the same table `my_table`

Comment: why you need  a self join  ..?

Comment: because the value to update comming from another column on the same table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking to your query seems you don't need  a self join but just an update

```
UPDATE my_table t1
SET 
    t1.hash1 =  UNHEX(MD5(t1.original)),
    t1.hash2 =  UNHEX(MD5(t1.translated))
WHERE t1.id < 1000;
```

*and the performance problem related  to your query is related  to the cartesian product between your tables*

Comment: :) ... Yes Sr. that is really improve performance `Query OK, 26385 rows affected (1.39 sec)`

Comment: seems  .. good result  ..  for performance  .. and for sql too

Answer (score 5):

This is doing a *cross join*, a Cartesian product:

```
UPDATE my_table t1, my_table t2 
SET 
    t1.hash1 =  UNHEX(MD5(t2.original)),
    t1.hash2 =  UNHEX(MD5(t2.translated))
WHERE t1.id < 1000;
```

You can calculate the number of attempted updates by doing:

```
select count(*)
from my_table t1 cross join my_table t2
where t1.id < 1000;
```

I won't be surprised if the answer is in the many millions.

You can get the count faster by doing:

```
select sum( id < 1000) * count(*)
from my_table ;
```

Moral?  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.